# How do I use Adobe Audition for Spatial Audio Mixing?

Tags: mixer, mastering, multichannel, remastering, ambisonics

I am looking for the best workflow to mixing/mastering bunch of wav files in an ambisonics file which has 4 channels(W,X,Y and Z).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a set of plugins/tools that allow you to up-mix mono and stereo files to B-Format. This will usually involve orientation of the incoming signal around three planes (pitch, roll, yaw). Were you to be using Reaper, the Ambisonic Toolkit is freely available for this purpose.

The workflow usually involves laying up your mono and stereo effects into a track, upmixing to B-Format via a plugin, then orienting the signal using an orientation plugin. Once you are in B-Format and oriented correctly you are able to mix this signal in B-Format.

Monitoring is generally performed using a B-Format to Binaural converter, often with head-tracking allowing you to perceive the full 360 degree sound space with headphones.

Comment: Can you suggest me few VST plugins that works best with the Adobe Premiere Pro or Adobe Audition CC?

Comment: I am not a user of either of those products, but I am aware of some products by a company called "Harpex" which may be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the best workflow to continue with Adobe products after trying out the popular VST plugins such as Facebook's Spatial Workstation and IEM Plug-in Suite but Matthias Kronlachner's Ambix encoder made my job much easier with Adobe Premiere Pro CC.

Here is the help link,
https://helpx.adobe.com/in/premiere-pro/using/VRSupport.html#AssemblingAmbisonicsAudio

I have used Ambix encoder(downloaded from http://www.matthiaskronlachner.com/) to position the stereo sound in the symmetric cube. To preview the output, I have used Binauralizer Ambisonics effect.

Thanks all for the help!